# search inside json kind of string in query using regular expression

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have string like `{"A":["3", "4", "5", "6"],"B":["3", "4", "5", "6"],"C":[{"2":"y"},{"3":"y"},{"4":"y"},{"5":"y"}],"D":["3", "4", "5", "6"]}`

I would like to search "5" inside B array means **"5"** and not in any other inside mysql query.

What would be the regular expression for that

Comment: If it's JSON, why not simply json_decode() it?

Comment: it is stored in database and in searching i would like to search for each record i can't decode each record and compare them

Comment: If the data had been properly normalised in the first place, then this wouldn't be an issue

Comment: http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/04/08/json-parsing-in-mysql-using-common-schema/ shows how to use [common_schema](http://code.google.com/p/common-schema/) functions to handle JSON in the database

Comment: if i dont store like this then i may need 5 to 6 columns for such records

Comment: World will burn, 5 or 6 columns! You do know can normalize your database and instead of 6 columns you can insert 6 rows which you can use for searches?

Comment: it would be appreciable if you can suggest proper regular expression for that searching

Comment: If you do store like this, then you encounter exactly the problem you've just encountered: any solution will be slow as it can't use an index, whereas if you'd normalized your data with indexes then you'd be able to do efficient searches

Comment: Your approach was bad. People here are posting comments to tell you how you can efficiently use the relational database to do what you need to. After all that you're still insisting on someone giving you the regular expression, which is by the way the worst way you can use to search. Given the fact you can't work with (good) ideas posted, how about you hire someone who can do the code the way you want it for you? This isn't "please give me code" type of website. If you need or want that, contact an expert and pay them.

Comment: The MySQL plug-in I suggested earlier, common_schema, will allow you to query against the json without having to use a regexp; but it still won't be particularly efficient as it can't use any indexes (but neither can a regexp solution). When it comes down to brass tacks, normalisation is the solution, and anything else is simply a painful workround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple and effective solution is `REGEXP '.*"B":\\[["0-9,]*"5"["0-9,]*\\]'`

Answer (score 2):

Mark Baker pretty much answered it for you: PHP already has a method for decoding json strings. It's easier than parsing yourself:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

EDIT: I saw your comment that this information is stored in the database. In which case, I wouldn't store a json string directly in a database. You're kind of defeating the purpose of relational databases by holding all of the information in one column.

Comment: yes php has but i would like to use that in query so i need regular expression for that

Comment: You're making it much more difficult than it has to be. Just add extra columns to your table so you can take advantage of the algorithms they worked so hard to make efficient. What you're trying to implement is only going to work slower and be less efficient. This is also going to be really unclear and confusing for anybody else that has to look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's json, use json_decode:

```
$str = '{"A":["3", "4", "5", "6"],"B":["3", "4", "5", "6"],"C":[{"2":"y"},{"3":"y"},{"4":"y"},{"5":"y"}],"D":["3", "4", "5", "6"]}';
$obj = json_decode($str);
echo $obj->{'B'}[2];
```

Output:

```
 5
```

Comment: that't true but i need regular expression to find it inside query not in php

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
REGEXP '"B":\[([^"\]]")*5"'
```